# Using a waveform to trigger case structure but ignoring falling edge

Tags: labview

Working on a project that uses a waveform we're looking at to trigger a case structure based on the amplitude. Problem is I want it to trigger multiple cases IE at 30 and 60, but when it hits 60 it will obviously drop below 60 and still be above 30. This causes the code in the higher structure to be effectively ignored. How do I get around this? I've tried an empty while loop that runs until it drops below 30, no luck.

To be a little more specific. I want to be able to trigger the top case, say 60 without triggering the lower case (30) on the way down. As in I hit 60, the action is done, but as soon as the waveform goes below 60 it will trigger the 30 case and effectively cancel out what was just done. Is there a way to make the program wait until it is less than 30 to check again?

[Case Structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxjCJ.png)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I think I know what you want, but I need a picture of your code to be sure. Can you post a picture showing your case structure? I'll go ahead and answer in the meantime, just in case I've guessed right.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is referred to as a [Edge Trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_edge), in this case watching for a rising edge.

So that the first time your value crosses past 30, a flag is put high. Then as it passes 60 a second flag is put high.
These flags only occur on the transition from "Less" to "Greater" so only occur in the one direction and only on the one period when that transition is reported.

[image: Parallel Edge Detection]

Comment: Interesting use of the feedback (feedforward?) nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A Case Structure can have more than one clause in the evaluation.

So you can have a case structure that activates on both 30 and 60 like this:

[image: 30 and 60]

Alternately, a case structure can have more than just two frames, and you can put in ranges, like this:

[image: ranges]

If you're working with floating-point data, you can't just wire the floats directly to the ? terminal (floating point is not an ordinal type), so you may need to convert to integer first with one of the coercion bullets:

[image: coercion bullet to integer]